# EF Code First schema design - User and Contact

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, poco, entity-framework-5

I'm trying to come up with a model for managing Person and its Friends.

- A Person has 0-to-many Friends
- A Friend is a Person too - not the same one though
- A Friend can belong one or more Groups

Roughly, the schema looks something like this:

[image]

I cannot figure out how to achieve the same with EF Code First. This is what I have so far but this doesn't create the required schema

```
public class Person 
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Person> Friends { get; set; } // is this right?
}

public class Friend {
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public long PersonId { get; set; }  // Person whose Friend this guy is
    public virtual ICollection<Group> Groups { get; set; } 

    // other fields 
}

public class Group{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Can someone help me figure out this mess?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need self referencing many-to-many relation on `Person` because you current model allows each person to have many friends but in the same time each person can be friend with only one other person.

Try this:

```
public class Person 
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Person> FriendWith { get; set; } 
    public virtual ICollection<Person> FriendOf { get; set; } 
}
```

And you can add this fluent-API mapping:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
            .HasMany(p => p.FriendWith)
            .WithMany(p => p.FriendOf)
            .Map(m => {
                 m.MapLeftKey("PersonId");
                 m.MapRightKey("FriendId");
                 m.ToTable("PersonFriends");
            });
```

It may seem strange but associations in EF builds oriented graph  => if a person A is friend with a person B it is considered as different relation then if a person B is friend with a person A. One of these relations will be in `FriendWith` collection and another will be in `FriendOf` collection.